# linking between backend on python code and flutter

Tags: python, flutter, frontend, backend

I am thinking of linking a backend code written in python to mobile application which I want to build its frontend on flutter; I tried starflut package and I downloaded a a sample code but it did not work, and I unfortunately did not understand what was written on flutter documentation about this library. Can anybody help me with this package, or recommend easier way to link between them?

Answer (score 7):

Tha starflut package is for compiling other scripting language along with your app, not connecting to python backend.

You cannot directly connect to backend. When you make backend in python, you need to write APIs (see [How to build rest api in Python](https://www.codementor.io/sagaragarwal94/building-a-basic-restful-api-in-python-58k02xsiq) ). Then from flutter you can connect to those APIs using [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package.

You can also checkout [this tutorial series in youtube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5tVJtjoxKzrC1dRdj9AsRKcYO33pK76P). Here the tutor teaches to build flutter app as well as simple backend in python.

Comment: I believe yes, if you are doing machine learning stuff in python..do it in server, if you want to do machine learning stuff on mobile look for ML kit for mobiles